# How to get all algebraic associative operations on a finite set by efficient algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, modeling, abstract-algebra, semigroup

Number of binary operation on a set of 2 elements is `2^(2*2)=16`.
    [image]
Number of associative binary operation on that set is only 8.
[image]
Number of binary operation on a set of 3 elements is 3^(3*3)=19683.
Number of associative binary operation on that set is only 113.
How to know how many associative binary operations there are on a set of n elements?

Also in order to get all this 113 operations and write into file, it is necessary to write a program.
if I will try to get all 19683 operations and then check it`s associative property "a*(b*c)==(a*b)*c" for all 19683 operations, this will work but this should take a long time for n=4 elements!
How to write an efficient algorithm to solve this task?
Please help me!

Comment: your question is way to broad, and probably also not very well focused for SO. SO is about programming and not about Combinatorics.

Comment: @JensGustedt This problem is more about algorithms than combinatorics.  Sure, you need the combinatorics to analyze the algorithm (a naive implementation would be something like `O(n^(n^2))` in complexity), but it isn't about combinatorics.  I would agree that this post might be better suited [programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), since they mention algorithms specifically in [their FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @bheklilr: Well, SO at least has an [algorithm tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithm/info) (and a tag for  abstract algebra and even one for semigroups). But I think, it's too broad, a good answer would probably be very long. Last, there is nothing OP has tried so far (it's a "gimme teh algo" question). IremadzeArchil:  Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/? Actually, you're asking “how many semigroups with n elements do exist?”

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/q/110211.

Comment: You might be able to find some good resources following http://oeis.org/A023814

Comment: Notice that every associative operation exhibits one or more of a couple types of symmetry, but the non-associative ones don't...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More than devising your own algorithm, this is a task for a mathematical model finder. For this task, I'd particularly recommend `mace4`, which part of [the LADR library](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/). It is specifically tuned to algebraic problems like this. The input (let's name it `semigroups.in`) would look like:

```
formulas(sos).
  (x * y) * z = x * (y * z).
end_of_list.
```

And then running it by `mace4 -n 4 -N 4 -m 10000 <semigroup.in` (find all 4-element models and print up to 10000 of them) produces a long output like

```
...

============================== MODEL =================================

interpretation( 4, [number=2331, seconds=0], [

        function(*(_,_), [
                           1, 2, 3, 3,
                           2, 3, 3, 3,
                           3, 3, 3, 3,
                           3, 3, 3, 3 ])
]).

============================== end of model ==========================

============================== STATISTICS ============================

For domain size 4.

Current CPU time: 0.00 seconds (total CPU time: 0.11 seconds).
Ground clauses: seen=64, kept=64.
Selections=2132, assignments=8520, propagations=6194, current_models=2331.
Rewrite_terms=210696, rewrite_bools=65151, indexes=11452.
Rules_from_neg_clauses=586, cross_offs=3767.

============================== end of statistics =====================

User_CPU=0.11, System_CPU=0.26, Wall_clock=0.

Exiting with 2331 models.
```

As you can see, it is *very* fast.

The library contains many other tools, such as `isofilter` that allows you to filter isomorphic variants of an algebra etc.

Comment: `Wall_clock=0` Apparently, bragging is a feature natively supported by this library. They really did think of everything...

Comment: @ParthianShot This seems more like an unimplemented feature.